# Font-awesome icon not clickable (React)

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to implement font-awesome icons with social media links, but for the uncertain reason, icons are not clickable and do not respond to transformation. Any ideas about how to fix it?

Here is the project in codesandox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/under-construction-7g68z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just give the #outerCraneContainer a z-index:-1

```
#outerCraneContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -60px 0 -30px #ff6347;
  z-index:-1; 
}
```

to push it behind the other elements

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your `#outerCraneContainer` styles, they cover the entire page (including the links), that's why you can not press any link.

Try to set `#outerCraneContainer` height to `height: 200px;` instead of `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

you have `div` with id `outerCraneContainer` which is displays over your icons and thus perventing them from being click.

solution: remove `position: absolute;` from app.css under

```
#outerCraneContainer {
  position: absolute; //remove this
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -60px 0 -30px #ff6347;
}
```